How to lock camera in react native to portrait mode only
How to lock the camera in react native to portrait mode only.
I have a screen where on button,click I open the device camera to click the document picture, Now I want to fix the camera to portrait mode only.
I have tried:
For Android, the AndroidManifest.xml file and the activity element added
'android:screenOrientation="portrait"' 

to lock to portrait.
Also, used a third party npm
with this method:
Orientation.lockToPortrait(); 

Then in App Navigator, for  <Stack.Screen compoent:
  options={{headerShown: false, orientation: 'portrait'}}

But none of these works for me, currently checking on Android only but I need this for both iOS and Android.

What I understand is that you want to check if the user is holding the device in portrait or landscape? So that you can check and perform actions in accordance. If so, the you will need the library 'react-native-orientation-locker' to detect the orientation using a listener. This is how you can achieve it (Just a sample code).
first import the library usage
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation-locker';

now declare a state
const [orientation, setOrientation] = useState('PORTRAIT');

update the state with orientation
useEffect(() => {
    const orientationDidChange = (newOrientation) => {
      setOrientation(newOrientation);
    };

    Orientation.addOrientationListener(orientationDidChange);

    return () => {
      Orientation.removeOrientationListener(orientationDidChange);
    };
  }, []);

